Kalman Filter and Generalized Least Squares
I have read in many places how Kalman Filter is related to generalized least squares algorithms. But there is still a bit I found a bit counterintuitive.
Kalman gain solution is  ${K}_k = {{P}}_{k\mid k-1}{H}_k^{T} {S}_k^{-1}$ where ${S}_k = {H}_k {{P}}_{k\mid k-1} {H}_k^{T} + {R}_k$ if we follow the wikipedia convention
Or $$K = PH^T ( H P H^T)^{-1} $$
If you allow me to drop the subscripts and measurement noise $R$ (assume we have perfect measurement) for the simplicity of ensuring discussion.
This looks very much like the solution to the Generalized Least Squares problem ($y \sim X \beta)$
$${\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}} = \left( \mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf{\Omega}^{-1} \mathbf{X} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{ \mathrm{T}}\mathbf{\Omega}^{-1}\mathbf{y}.$$
But here, the weights on the solution is $\Omega^{-1}$. Where $\Omega$ is the error covariance matrix. Note the matrix inverse.
What I don't understand is, why do we weight by the inverse of the error covariance matrix in generalized least squares, but by error covariance matrix $P$ in Kalman Filter? Where did the inverse disappear?

$\mathbf{P}$ is the state estimate covariance matrix. $\mathbf{K}$ is the Kalman gain, used to update the state and state covariance matrix. $\mathbf{R}$ is the measurement covariance matrix. If you include $\mathbf{R}_{k}$ in the inverse of $\mathbf{S}$ and use the woodbury identity, you will see $\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ in there.

You need to write down how $K$ and $\beta$ are solved (which optimization problem under which constraint).

Imagine you are solving this recursive least squares problem
$(x-x_0)^T \Pi_0^{-1}(x-x_0) + || H_{i} x - Y_i ||^2 $
at each step $i-1$, you already have a solution $\hat{x}_{i-1}$ to
$(x-x_0)^T \Pi_0^{-1}(x-x_0) + || H_{i-1} x - Y_{i-1} ||^2 $
and you are trying to go from $\hat{x}_{i-1}$ to $\hat{x}_{i}$
Here $H_i = \begin{bmatrix} H_{i-1} \\ h_i \end{bmatrix}$. Let's assume $x_0 = 0$
Solving this least squares problem,
$\hat{x}_{i} = P_i H_i^T Y_i$, where $P_i = (\Pi_0^{-1} + H_i^T H_i)^{-1}$ and $P_i^{-1} = P_{i-1}^{-1} + h_i^T h_i$
Basically, $P_i$ is already an inverse, kind of. You can then try to add a weight $|| H_{i} x - Y_i ||_W^2$ to your objective function and it starts to look awfully like Kalman Filter.
It's obviously not a complete derivation of Kalman Filter, but that's the "intuitive" part you are looking for.

It is not an apples to apples comparison.
The Kalman Filter is a Bayesian estimator, minimizing the MMSE Risk Function, while the Least Squares is a Parametric estimator.
Indeed, one can show that the Regularized Least Squares problem can be equivalent of the MMSE / MAP estimator of the Bayesian approach. See How Is the Formula for the Wiener Deconvolution Derived.
The Kalman Filter can be expressed as a Least Squares problem as given in How to Regularize the State Variables of a Kalman Filter.
Specifically in your case, you compare the estimation of the parameters of the LS to the estimation of the Gain of Kalman filter which is not the objective.
A better comparison would be comparing the Kalman Gain to the Gain of the Sequential Least Squares (SLS) filter (For some reason also called Recursive Least Squares [RLS] filter).
You may look for the derivation of the Gain of the SLS in Sequential Form of the Least Squares Estimator for Linear Least Squares Model.
You'd see that in the SLS the gain is only a function of the empirical covariance of the measurements and the model matrix.
While in the Kalman filter it is a function of both the Measurements Covariance and the Process Covariance (Since the model is Bayesian) as incorporated in $\boldsymbol{P}$.
The similarity happens as (Using Wikipedia - Kalman Filter notations) $\boldsymbol{P}$ depends on $\boldsymbol{K}$ which depends on the inverse of $\boldsymbol{S}$ which is the covariance o the measurements, like the in LS filter. Here I use the Estimation part of the Kalman Filter where the prediction error is basically the estimations it tries to smooth.

Thanks Royi. I can follow the math, but I just struggle to understand, intuitively, why does one involve error covariance matrix and the other involve the inverse of the error covariance matrix?

@JoshBolton, Both use the inverse. Remember that $\boldsymbol{K}$ depends on the inverse of $\boldsymbol{S}$ which is the covariance matrix of the prediction error which can be thought as the measurements for the Kalman estimator.
